# Making files read-only until checked out

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need to make the project files read-only by default, and make them writable if and only if I check out the files for local editing.

I thought that was the default behavior, but for some reason I lost it. How could I get it back?

(My ultimate intention is to prevent developers from editing files without first checking out.)

Comment: Are you using a Local or Server Workspace, Local Workspaces don't set the readonly flag on the files.

Comment: How do you intend to keep the devs from turning off the R flag manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using the "[Local Workspaces](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx)" feature of TFS 2012.

This means all files are writeable and do not need to be checked out to remove the read-only flag (much like SVN and Git). As soon as you make a change to a file, it will be checked out.

You can change TFS to [default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/05/set-local-workspaces-as-default-when-upgrading-to-tfs-2012.aspx) to Server Workspaces, or just setup workspaces as Server Workspaces for each developer.

Comment: Thank you for this!  Also note that when you use "Local Workspaces" it creates a new folder called "$tf" in your project folder that it fills with TFS data.  For people who are using file sync services like Google Drive or Dropbox it fills up your cloud with garbage.  To change an existing project back to a "Server Workspace", go to Source Control Explorer->Workspaces->Edit->Advanced->Location and change the value back to "Server" from "Local".  The garbage folder will then magically disappear and all your checked-in files will get marked read-only as they should be.

Comment: Just want to update this fine comment above - for those who are using the eclipse plugin, this is the path to the correct setting is: in Pending Changes --> actions button --> Manage Workspaces --> Edit --> Advanced